# How are distributions besides normal distribution used?

Tags: distributions

I just finished my first applied Stats class and learned about how are z-scores 
and t -statistics are used to calculate the probability under the curve.

Are there other scores used for the other type of distributions like Poisson, Pareto, exponential distributions?

Answer (score 1):

I may misunderstand you question, my answer is Yes, every other distributions you mentioned have "scores" or "quantiles" to calculate the probability.

```
pnorm(1.96,0,1) # for z socre
#p= 0.9750021 this p value for z score

pt(1.8,10)   #for t distribution
# p=0.9489739

#for Poisson

ppois(10, lambda = 10)

#p=0.5830398
```

For Pareto,exponential it is the same. I will not write down here you may search internet download some related libraries.